# Jasmine Test sort() localecompare()

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How do I write a jasmine test for below code:

```html
var items = ['réservé', 'premier', 'cliché', 'communiqué', 'café', 'adieu'];
items.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)); // ['adieu', 'café', 'cliché', 'communiqué', 'premier', 'réservé']
```

How do I spy on sort() with two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions here. The first one is too broad and vague, so I will not be answering it. The second one in straightforward. To spy on the Array `sort` method simply put this in a spec of a `beforeEach` block:

```
spyOn(Array.prototype, 'sort');
```

What's happening here is that the `sort` method on your array is actually the same one that is defined on the Array's prototype object.

Comment: I also want to test if localeCompare haveBeenCalled, I am not able to figure it out how to Spy on that.
I am getting an error: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'a.localeCompare)

Comment: Should it be `spyOn(String.prototype, "localeCompare");`

Comment: OK. You had said above that you had wanted to spy on `sort`. In order to make sure that you are not getting a `TypeError` for `localeCompare` you need to make sure that you are only using strings in the test. Can you update your question and include all of the test that you currently have?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create different spy for both `sort` as well as `localeCompare`.

```
spyOn(Array.prototype,'sort').and.callThrough();
spyOn(String.prototype,'localeCompare'); // Add callThrough() if you want to verify the order
```

This way you get to spy on both methods.

Now, if you want to check if the order is correct, then create a basic function to check the order.

**Example method to check ascending:** (Its in Typescript, but you get the logic)

```
public static isAscending(array: Array<string>): boolean { 
    let isAscending = false;
    let prev = array[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (i != array.length - 1) {
            if (prev < array[i + 1]) {
                isAscending = true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (isAscending) {
        return true;
    }
}
```